# How do I create column calculated from another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a column `age` in a SQL Server database.

The values of this column should be calculated based on the values of the column `DOB`.

Also its values should increment as `Age` increases.

Comment: and what about newly added rows?

Comment: Only when you select the values of the table or rather when you access anyone would know if the age is upto date. So you can use a trigger/stored proecedure to do that.. isn't it? [something on similar lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329149/calculating-age-from-birthday-with-oracle-plsql-trigger-and-insert-the-age-in-ta)

Comment: I would simply create a VIEW on top of the table with the last column of the view definition as `datediff(yy, DOB, getUTCDate())`.

Comment: Create a view that calculates the age. There is no need to store this kind of information.

Comment: Oh look, a homework question :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use a computed column to solve this problem. Something with a definition similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD Age AS datediff(year, DOB ,getdate())
```

Original statement taken from and further information available at [BlackWasp](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLComputedColumns.aspx).

Edit:

MSDN explains computed columns as:

> A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other
>   columns in the same table. The expression can be a noncomputed column
>   name, constant, function, and any combination of these connected by
>   one or more operators. The expression cannot be a subquery.
>
> Unless otherwise specified, computed columns are virtual columns that
>   are not physically stored in the table. Their values are recalculated
>   every time they are referenced in a query. The Database Engine uses
>   the PERSISTED keyword in the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements
>   to physically store computed columns in the table. Their values are
>   updated when any columns that are part of their calculation change. By
>   marking a computed column as PERSISTED, you can create an index on a
>   computed column that is deterministic but not precise. Additionally,
>   if a computed column references a CLR function, the Database Engine
>   cannot verify whether the function is truly deterministic. In this
>   case, the computed column must be PERSISTED so that indexes can be
>   created on it. For more information, see Creating Indexes on Computed
>   Columns.
>
> Computed columns can be used in select lists, WHERE clauses, ORDER BY
>   clauses, or any other locations in which regular expressions can be
>   used, with the following exceptions:
>
> Computed columns used as CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, or NOT NULL constraints must be marked 
>   PERSISTED. A computed column can be used as a key column in an index or as part of any 
>   PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint if the computed column value is defined by a 
>   deterministic expression and the data type of the result is allowed in index
>   columns.
>
> For example, if the table has integer columns a and b, the computed column a + b can be 
>   indexed, but computed column a + DATEPART(dd, GETDATE()) cannot be indexed because the 
>   value may change > in subsequent invocations.
>
> A computed column cannot be the target of an INSERT or UPDATE statement.
>
> The Database Engine automatically determines the nullability of
>   computed columns based on the expressions used. The result of most
>   expressions is considered nullable even if only nonnullable columns
>   are present, because possible underflows or overflows will produce
>   null results as well. Use the COLUMNPROPERTY function with the
>   AllowsNull property to investigate the nullability of any computed
>   column in a table. An expression that is nullable can be turned into a
>   nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant),
>   where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result.

Source: [MSDN - Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I suggest you add some info here, too, not just the link. Like what is a computed column, can this be peristed, can it be indexed, etc.

Comment: Done. I took the liberty of quoting MSDN

Comment: very nice description, but it really doesn't find the age. It finds the difference in whole years between 2 dates. DOB = '2012-12-31', getdate() = '2013-01-01' = 1 year

Answer (score 5):

Code snippet

```
ALTER TABLE
    TheTable
ADD
    DOB AS
    CASE
        WHEN
                MONTH(Birth) > MONTH(ISNULL(Death, SYSDATETIME()))
            OR  (
                        MONTH(Birth) = MONTH(ISNULL(Death, SYSDATETIME()))
                    AND DAY(Birth) >= DAY(ISNULL(Death, SYSDATETIME()))
                )
        THEN
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birth, ISNULL(Death, SYSDATETIME())) - 1
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birth, ISNULL(Death, SYSDATETIME()))
    END
```

Answer (score 3):

Create Table with auto-generated column,

```
CREATE TABLE Person2
(Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Name nvarchar(50),
DOB date, Age AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB ,GETDATE()) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way of getting the age:

```
alter table <yourtable> add age as datediff(year, DOB, getdate())- case when month(DOB)*32 + day(DOB) > month(getdate()) * 32 + day(getdate()) then 1 else 0 end
```