# How to update the age column if age column is null based on date of birth column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to update the age column if age column is null based on date of birth column in oracle?
table t1:(Source Table)

```
Name        dob        age
aaa     12-JUN-1985
bbb     15-MAY-1991
ccc     23-AUG-2000
```

Target table like this:

```
Name        dob        age
aaa     12-JUN-1985    28 
bbb     15-MAY-1991    22 
ccc     23-AUG-2000    13
```

Comment: if you are entering the DOB then Y do U need to explicitly put the age.?

Comment: Are you going to increase all age records next year? Better create a calculated field that returns the age based on the Date of birth and the current date

Comment: i'm with my friends here - you need to create a view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating age from birthday with oracle plsql trigger and insert the age in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329149/calculating-age-from-birthday-with-oracle-plsql-trigger-and-insert-the-age-in-ta)

Comment: Actually there are situations in which we have to calculate AGE.  The point being that the AGE is the age of the person at the time when the record is created or at the time of the event the record represents, rather than their age now.  You would not want to be calculating ages on the fly to satisfy a query for "everybody who had a heart attack under the age of 40".

Answer (score 2):

```
update the_table
  set age = months_between(current_date, dob) / 12
where age is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table
   SET age =trunc(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12)
 WHERE age is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
UPDATE <your table> SET age = NVL(age, MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate,dob)/12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely in the camp of this should be a calculated field based off date of birth as you'll constantly have to update it.

If you need to do it, I'd suggest:

```
UPDATE [YOUR TABLE]
SET age = NVL(age, 24 * (sysdate - dob)/8766)
```

This will take into account leap years by using hours: `8766/24 = 365.25`

[Info on NVL function for substituting null values](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php)